# HTML CSS Javascript Hamburger Menu problem

Tags: javascript, html, css, hamburger-menu

would someone mind looking at a website please? The address is test.dvps.uk/index.html

I'm having issues with the Hamburger Menu, its in a 50% column and I want it right aligned. I've tried align content, floating and different position and displays but can seem to get it right. The other problem i'm having is that when the menu is toggled, it expands but pushes the content down of the container below but I want it to move the container too.

I'm sure that my tinkering to align the menu has caused this issue, so before I break it any further would you mind helping, please?  Thank you :)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".hamburger").click(function() {
    $(".nav").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Arial";
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 10px;
  max-width: 1000px;
}

.container-bottom-pad {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 10px;
  max-width: 1000px;
  padding-bottom: 80px;
}

.outerContainer {
  background-color: #F1F1F1;
}

.row::before,
.row::after {
  display: table;
  content: " ";
  clear: both;
}

.row {
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.one,
.one-third,
.two-thirds,
.one-fourth {
  width: 100%;
}

#headerAndNav {
  background-color: rgba(135, 196, 66, 0.60);
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

header img {
  z-index: -2;
  position: absolute;
  width: 20%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.header-logo {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: auto;
}

.nav {
  display: none;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Makes the sliding animation cleaner */
}

.nav-item {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  background: #87c442;
  display: block;
  margin: 12px 0;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 6px #2c3e50;
}

.nav-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}

.nav-item:active {
  box-shadow: none;
  transform: translate(0px, 6px);
  transition: transform .20s;
}

.hamburger span {
  display: block;
  width: 35px;
  height: 4px;
  background: #625948;
  margin: 5px 0px;
  padding: 0;
}

.hamburger:hover span {
  transition: background ease-in-out .25s;
  background: #87c442;
}

.hamburger:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" id="headerAndNav">
  <div class="row">
    <header>
      <div class="eleven-twelths column">
        <nav>
          <span class="flex-container">
                    <div class="align">
                        <div class="hamburger">
                            <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="login.html">Login</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="signup.html">Signup</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="successes.html">Successes</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="prices.html">Prices</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="about.html">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
  </span>
  </nav>
</div>
<div class="one-twelth column">
  <img alt="logo" class="header-logo" src="images/site/opaque-logo.png">
</div>
<!-- end of one-twelth-->
</div>
<!-- end of row -->
</header>
</div>
<!-- end of container -->
```

Comment: Maybe try adding your css and html code ? It'll be hard to help you with what you provided us

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Include code to reproduce the problem. Take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I thought look at the website in developer view would useful but i'll copy out the menu and css code

Comment: The reason that we require code in your question is that once your problem is solved there’s no need for you continue hosting the broken/demonstration code, which means - if you delete that code - that future visitors can’t derive any benefit from your question, and, while we’re trying to solve your problem we’re also tying to help those who are struggling with the same, or similar, problems in future.

Comment: That makes sense 

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want a brute force solution, just do this in the CSS file:

```
.hamburger { position:fixed; top: 25px; right: 30px; }
```

This will take the hamburger div out from the document flow and it will always stick to the given position.

I see a couple other issues arising on the horizon, but keep going.

And take the whole align div out of the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

After looking the adress you mention (test.dvps.uk/index.html) and following your questions:

1)**" *... the Hamburger Menu, its in a 50% column and I want it right aligned ...*"**

The problems it's related to the div with class ***flex-container*** and the next div with class ***align*** (and note you have two definitions of class ***align***: one floating right and the other floating left!)

2) ***...pushes the content down of the container below but I want it to move the container too...***

You can try with ***clear: right*** in the container after the menu.

Also you must note some properties in your file ***custom.css*** are misspelled (i.e *bot* instead *bottom*). Check it out this too.

I hope this help.

Saludos!

Comment: Hiya. Thank you! Why is hearder-half a problem in relation to the location of the menu? Thank you for the heads up on the CSS, I will check through it.

Comment: You are rigth. Touching header-half was a dirty fix but not the real problem.  I've edited my answer.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you, again :)

Answer (score 0):

1) The alignment, as noted by others, is due to the flex container. Add:

`justify-content: flex-end` to right align.

2) The toggled menu pushing the content down is due to the DOM being changed (think of it as an element that goes from 0px width/height to 100px width/height). The easiest fix is to take the element out of the DOM flow. One way is using `position`. So, an example:

`position: absolute; right: 0; z-index: 1` to `ul.nav`

Your hamburger should now be right aligned, and the hamburger content should not interfere/push down the other content.